# How ATM Surveillance Camera works?

Tags: surveillance, defense, atm

I would like to know how the ATM pin hole camera works.Whether the pin hole camera works only once the card is inserted in ATM or during the cash withdrawal or it works always?

Comment: lol asking for a legitimate reason I take it?  I'm not sure banks normally disclose details about their security.

Comment: Are you referring to the bank's security camera, or the PIN-stealing camera used as part of a card skimmer?

Answer (score 1):

I interned at JP Morgan last summer. They said their ATM's cameras were on all the time. It may vary depending on the bank though.